# What explains the output of this C code?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct abc{
  int a;
  int b;
} xyz;

int main()
{
  xyz.a = 10;
  xyz.b = 20;
  printf("%d %d", xyz, xyz.a);
}
```

The output of of the above program is `10 20`.

If I add another `printf` statement as

```
printf("%d %d %d", xyz, xyz.a, xyz.b);
```

the output comes `10 20 10`.

What's the explanation for this?

Comment: Mine returns `10 10`. Relying on undefined behavior is not a good idea. :)

Comment: @sarnold, yours returned `10 10`. You were lucky, mine created a miniature black hole which swallowed up my wife, the two kids, the dog, and my main machine. I'm having to type this comment on my old 386 clunker. Geez, I'm gonna miss that dog :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo sorry to hear about your dog.

Comment: @paxdiablo: That serves you right for running code from a SO question on a DS9000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've invoked **undefined behavior**; *any* result is allowed.

> **7.19.6.1 The fprintf function**
> ...
> 9 If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined.<sup>248)</sup> **If any argument is
>      not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is
>       undefined.**

Emphasis mine.  `xyz` is of type `struct abc`, but `printf` is expecting that argument to be type `int`.

paxdiablo's answer is a decent postmortem of how such a result *may* occur, but that's only applicable to your specific circumstances.  Change *anything* about the code or the translation environment or the execution environment, and the result will probably be different.

Answer (score 15):

It's because the call to `printf` is pushing the *entire structure* `xyz` onto the stack and that structure (in this case) consists of the two integers. The `xyz.a` in that case is ignored since it's beyond the stack area that `printf` cares about.

Although the behaviour is undefined<sup>(a)</sup> so that anything can happen, this particular case can be explained because the `printf("%d %d",xyz,xyz.a);` statement probably pushes `xyz` and `xyz.a` on to the stack something like:

```
xyz.a | 10 |    |
xyz   | 20 |    | Stack grows downward.
      | 10 |    V
```

and the `printf` code itself, because it's been given two `%d`'s, will print the 10 at the bottom and the 20. In other words, it's a mismatch between the format string and the parameters.

When you add another `%d`, it prints what it thinks is the third argument (but is actually the second), the top 10 in the above diagram.

I should mention that relying on this behaviour is not a good idea. It may change when you switch compilers, versions of the compiler, or possibly even on odd-numbered days :-)

Good compilers like `gcc` actually look inside the `printf` arguments to catch this as a potential error:

```
pax$ cat qq.c
#include<stdio.h>
struct abc { int a; int b; } xyz;
int main (void) {
    xyz.a=10;
    xyz.b=20;
    printf("%d %d",xyz,xyz.a);
    return 0;
}

pax$ gcc -Wall -o qq qq.c
qq.c: In function 'main':
qq.c:6: warning: format '%d' expects type 'int',
        but argument 2 has type 'struct abc'
qq.c:6: warning: format '%d' expects type 'int',
        but argument 2 has type 'struct abc'
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> From c99, section `7.19.6.1/9`: *If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.*

Comment: Strictly speaking, the behavior is **undefined**; *any* result is allowed.

Comment: Sorry, John, I had implementation _dependent_. I didn't mean to indicate that it was implementation _defined_ (which has a very definite meaning under ISO C) but I've clarified it to remove any chance of confusion.